# Title page and half-title inside book

Tags: titles, book-design, page, book-class

Is theire a package or core command to automatically generate [title page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_page) and [half-title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-title) witch follow the page cover *inside* a `book`’s class document?

Comment: The `scrbook` class has an `\extratitle` macro precisely for this purpose. Would that be an option?